# Sum of bivariate normal distribution question. In need of clarification.

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics, normal-distribution

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ have a bivariate normal distribution with parameters $\mu_1 = \mu_2 = 0, \sigma_1 = \sigma_2 = 1, \rho = 0.5$. 
Find the probability that all of the roots of the following equation are real:
$X_1x^2 + 2X_2x + X_1 = 0$ 
Hint: Answer the following two questions first: Are $X_1 + X_2$ and $X_1 - X_2$ bivariate normally distributed? Are they mutually independent?

My answer to the hint is yes they are bivariate normally distribution (closure property of normal distributions).
I mean I know that $\rho = 0.5$ means that the 2 variables within $X_1$ and $X_2$ themselves are not independent so that means that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not mutually independent right?
For the roots to be real means, I need to evaluate $P[(2X_2)^2-4X_1^2 \ge 0] = P[4X_2^2-4X_1^2 \ge 0] = P[X_2^2-X_1^2 \ge 0] = P[X_2^2 \ge X_1^2]$
Now since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the same, therefore the probability evaluates to 0.5? Also I don't get where the hint is suppose to lead me?
Please help and thanks!

Edit:
Change of Variable
Let transformation be $U = X_1 + X_2$ and $V = X_1 - X_2$
Inverse Transformation: $X_1 = \frac{U+V}{2}$ and $X_2 = \frac{U-V}{2}$
Jacobian det = -2
$f_{U,V} = \frac{1}{\left|-2\right|}f_{X1,X2}(\frac{u+v}{2},\frac{u-v}{2})$

Comment: $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not **same** They are dependent random variables

Comment: but I thought they share the exact same parameters?

Comment: Yes, but(by not **same** , I meant)  you cannot say $P[X_1^2>X_2^2]=1/2$ because they are not independent,

Comment: oh ok.. erm then how do I evaluate that probability?

Comment: Try to understand the hint

Comment: My answers to the hint questions are correct right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the hint you wont be able to solve the problem.

Check that $U(=X_1+X_2)$ and $V=(X_1-X_2)$ follow bivariate normal with parameters $(0,0,2\times1.5=3,2\times0.5=1,0 )$

So $$P[X_1^2-X_2^2>0]=P[UV>0]=P[U>0,V>0]+P[U<0,V<0]$$

Now you need to find the joint distribution of $U$ and $V$ .Use the bivariate normal distribution.$$f_{U,V}(u,v)={1\over 2\pi\sqrt{|\Sigma|}}e^{1\over 2}\{(u \ v)\Sigma^{-1}(u\ v)^T\}$$

Comment: how did you get those parameters?

Comment: Var$(U)=2\sigma^2(1+\rho)$ and Var$(V)=2\sigma^2(1-\rho)$

Comment: I add some more workings. Is it something like this?

Comment: @matthew.j Absolutely. Only $\rho=0$ will make calculations easier!

Comment: is there a reference you could point me to regarding those parameters? I'm searching the internet for it but can't seem to find. Like I'm trying to wrap around how you got the new mean, var, correlation values. by the way thanks for your help!

Comment: Var$(X_1+X_2)=$ Var$(X_1)$+Var$(X_2)$+$2$Covar$(X_1,X_2)=\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2+2\rho \sigma_1\sigma_2\\$. There you go!

Comment: ooh... okok. thanks!!!